Mostrar contenido en una parte de mi componente de React
Dentro de mi componente simplemente quiero mostrar un artículo donde dependiendo de en dónde se encuentre (en el carrito o en el área de comprar) se muestren ciertos botones, si son de eliminar o agregar, pero dentro de este también quiero mostrar la cantidad de productos que se encuentran en el carrito. Ahí está el problema: siempre que voy agregando o quitando, no importa que haga dentro del h5, siempre se mostrará 1, hasta hice una función donde me devuelve el mismo valor pero haciendo un mensaje en consola del valor que recibe, y efectivamente el valor sí se actualiza.
Acá el componente:
import { typeProduct } from "../types/shopping_type";

type Props = {
  data: typeProduct;
  success: (id: number) => void;
  type: "Eliminar todos" | "Agregar";
  restProduct?: (id: number) => void;
};

function ProductItem(props: Props) {
  const { data, success, type, restProduct } = props;
  const { name, price, id, amount } = data;

  const handleRestClick = () => restProduct && restProduct(id);

  // console.log(amount);
  return (
    <div
      className="product"
      style={{ padding: "1rem", border: "thin solid #222" }}
    >
      <h4>{name}</h4>
      <h5>${price}</h5>
      {amount && (
        <h5>
          x{amount}${price * amount} //PROBLEMA**
        </h5>
      )}

      {amount && amount !== 1 && (
        <button onClick={handleRestClick}>Eliminar uno</button>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => success(id)}>{type}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProductItem;

Simplemente quiero saber qué pasa, no le hallo lógica y puedo confirmar que la propiedad amount sí funciona bien porque sí funciona en el resto del componente.
He probado haciendo mensajes a consola, cambiando la lógica y nada, abriendo y cerrando el servidor local, pero nada.

Parece que falta reactivar el estado amount,  al dar click en handleRestClick  hay que disparar un re-render del componente ProductItem, esto se puede lograr declarando un estado con useState al inicio del componente. Algo como const [localAmount, setLocalAmount] = useState(amount).
